# Silverstripe assumes SiteTree relation is to Parent?

Tags: orm, silverstripe

My (partial) DataObject:

```
class InternalExternalLink extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'ExternalLink' => 'VarChar(256)',
        'LinkLabel' => 'VarChar(256)',
        "LinkType" => "Enum(array('Internal', 'External','Attachment'))"
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'InternalLink' => 'SiteTree',
        'Attachment' => 'File'
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = new FieldList(array(
            $internal = DropdownField::create("InternalLinkID", "Choose a page", SiteTree::get()->map()->toArray())->setEmptyString("-- choose --"),
        ));
        return $fields;
    }
```

Add I add this to Page:

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Links' => 'InternalExternalLink'
    );

    function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $gridField = new GridField('Links', 'Links', $this->Links(), GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create());
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', $gridField);
        return $fields;
    }
```

The problem is when adding Links via the gridfield it automatically assumes that the Link.InternalLink is the parent page, rather than any page, and hides the page select drop down. E.g. if I am editing the about-us page then every Link dataobject I add via the gridfield automatically sets its InternalLink to the about-us page.

How do I change this assumption to allow me to select any page via the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Give the DataObject a "Parent" relation:

```
class InternalExternalLink extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Parent' => 'DataObject',    
        'InternalLink' => 'SiteTree',
        'Attachment' => 'File'
    );

    ...
}
```

2) Specify "Parent" in the page's has_many:

```
class LinkTestPage extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Links' => 'InternalExternalLink.Parent'
    );

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the relation on `InternalExternalLink` is to `SiteTree` whereas you're trying to define a relationship back to it on `Page`. As there's no `has_one` from `InternalExternalLink` to `Page`, and you're using a slightly older version of 3.1, the default `has_one` of `Parent` is looked for.

To solve this, you can either change the `InternalLink` relation to point to `Page` instead of `SiteTree` or use a `DataExtension` to add the `has_many` relation on to `SiteTree`.

Comment: Hi Simon, so the problem is I don't have a $has_one relationship on InternalExternalLink that points back to Page? This is why it's using the $has_one 'InternalLink' relationship instead? So I would need both - a Parent relationship and a relationship to another SiteTree object. Can you also outline what behaviour has changed in the recent 3.1 releases you refer to?

Comment: Also - what is "the default has_one of Parent is looked for" behaviour, is this documented anywhere? Thanks!